# How can I add namespace for multi events declaration using on() to unbind them later with off()?

Tags: jquery, events

According to the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/), a namespace can be declare like this to be used with `on` and `off` :

```
var validate = function () {
  // code to validate form entries
};

// delegate events under the ".validator" namespace
$("form").on("click.validator", "button", validate);

$("form").on("keypress.validator", "input[type='text']", validate);

// remove event handlers in the ".validator" namespace

$("form").off(".validator");
```

But how to declare a namespace for a multi events declaration in order to unbind them later using `off()` ?

```
$('#frame-right').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('#frame-right').off(???)
```

Comment: same like in example one or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the namespace to each individual event name:

```
$("#frame-right").on(
    "mousewheel.ns DOMMouseScroll.ns MozMousePixelScroll.ns",
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
);
```

Then you can issue:

```
$("#frame-right").off(".ns");
```